# RSpec Unit Testing controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

am relatively new with rspec and testing,am trying to write a test for this code

```
@assessments = Assessment.where(assigned_user_id: current_user.id)
```

here is what i have tried so far,but am not sure if it's the right way,i was told controller spec is not advisable,hence i am trying to implement it using unit test.

spec_file

```
    require 'rails_helper'

# Test suite for the assessment model
RSpec.describe Assessment, type: :model do
  let(:admin) { User.new(email: 'rockcoolsaint@example.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password', role: :admin) }
  let(:behavioral_specialist) { User.new(email: 'bs@example.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password', role: :behavioral_specialist) }
  let(:behavioral_specialist_2) { User.new(email: 'bs2@example.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password', role: :behavioral_specialist) }
  let(:bs_user_assessments) { Assessment.where(assigned_user_id: behavioral_specialist.id) }

  describe 'Validations' do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:title) }

    it 'is valid with all attributes' do
      expect(build(:assessment, user: admin, assigned_user: behavioral_specialist)).to be_valid
    end

    it 'is valid if assigned_user_id equals behavioral_specialist_id' do
      bs_user_assessments.each do |assessment|
        expect(assessment.assigned_user_id).to eq(behavioral_specialist.id)  
      end
    end

    it 'is valid if assigned_user_id does not equal behavioral_specialist_2_id' do
      bs_user_assessments.each do |assessment|
        expect(assessment.assigned_user_id).to_not eq(behavioral_specialist_2.id)  
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: It appears that you are trying to test ActiveRecord's `where` clause. Don't do that. The Rails core team has already done that for you. I would remove your last two tests completely and call it good.

Comment: How do you mean rails core team has done that already?

Comment: Your last two tests appear to be testing the functionality of ActiveRecord's `where` clause. You can trust that this functionality has been tested before by the Rails core team. I think what you really want is to use a double to ensure that you are calling `Assessment.where` with the correct parameters. Does that makes sense?

Comment: It would make a lot of sense with a little example please.

Comment: Can you update your post to show the line you want to test in context? That will help me give you an example of what I would test and how.